# How use LINQ to find entities where a list of sub entities contains another list

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have a complex object which contains 2 lists of more complex objects.

The first object is as follows:

```
public object1 {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<object2> objects2 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<object3> objects3 { get; set; }
}
```

Where as object2 and object3 are the same, having an ID and Name field. Such as:

```
public object {
   public int ID{ get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use a list / array of IDs (int[] ids) to search a list of 'object1's so that the field 'objects2' contains all the array o2_ids and 'objects3' all the array o3_ids (each one is int[]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from o1 in obj1List
where o2_ids.All(o2id => o1.objects2.Any(o2 => o2.ID == o2id))
&& o3_ids.All(o3id => o1.objects3.Any(o3 => o3.ID == o3id))
select o1
```

Comment: Thank you, but that wouldn't work. 'contains' expect an object of type 'object2' or 'object3', where as o2id/o3id is an int. There is not where a reference to the ID of object2 or object3. Could you revise please?

Comment: You're right, sorry - I've updated now to use `Any()` with a proper predicate.